# Character string operation

Tags: c++, character, operation

In C++, what happens if I have

```
S[6] = "word";
```

and then I have:

```
S[x] - '0';
```

where x is 0 - 4 ... What does that line?

Comment: Those two statements conflict. You assign a string to an element of `S` and then later use an element of `S` like a character. Sure it's possible to do that, but it doesn't make much sense, particularly without showing a complete example.

Comment: What is the type of `S`?

Comment: char S[6]; | I don't know what does the last line

Comment: @Maurice, In that case, `S[6]` is undefined behaviour and `S[validIndex] = "word";` doesn't compile. I have a guess as to what you're asking and what the answer is, but you'll need to seriously improve your question to the point where I can be 99.9% sure that it's right because the question is clearly conveyed. Right now, the title is not informative, the little bit of code shown doesn't make sense, the text provided with the code does very little to explain it, and the question is missing at least one word.

Comment: If you have `char S[6] = "word";` then you have legitimate code (but why on earth did you omit the `char` from the question?).  If you have `char S[6]; S[6] = "word";`, you have seriously broken code.  The short answer is that the value of `'0'` (which is usually 48 — on most platforms and in most code sets — but that is not guaranteed; for example, it is 240 on IBM mainframes using EBCDIC) is subtracted from each element of `S` in turn.  But since the value is not assigned, the calculation does nothing useful, so the compiler will discard it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your program is something like this:

```
int main()
{
  char S[6] = "word";
  for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    cout << S[i] - '0' << endl;
}
```

the first time `S[i] - '0'` calculates `'w' - '0'`, which are the ascii values of the characters (`'w' == 119` and `'0' == 48`). So it results in `71`.

The whole output is:

```
71
63
66
52
```

which is not really useful.

`S[i] + 'A' - 'a'` would be useful. It will change the lower case characters to upper case (assuming that there are only lower chase characters in the string)

Comment: ASCII? Probably not. The question doesn't state the character set and encoding of either the source file nor the compile target but the system default is the like one, which is probably UTF-8 or Windows-1252 (or similar). The [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html) explains it well.